# Как исключить многократную загрузку Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension, javascript-events

В расширении Google Chrome, установлено событие, которое отслеживает загрузку определенной страницы сайта `exemple.com`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Выполняемое действие;
});
```

Если страница будет открыта многократно,то и javascript код будет исполняться множество раз. Возможно ли событие поправить таким образом, чтобы исключить многократную загрузку Javascript? Вроде: Открыли браузер, загрузили страницу, событие отработало и ждет следующего открытия браузера и загрузки страницы.

Comment: Можете добавить флаг в `sessionStorage`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @Валерий Орлов, не совсем понятен вопрос, если вы каждый раз перезагружаете страницу, то и js будет работать каждый раз иначе в чем смысл? Если вы хотите сохранить какие то данные при выполнении js то можно записать их в сессии. Например эффекты должны выполняться при каждой загрузке/перезагрузке страницы, а если вы отмените js то и эффекты не будут работать.